# filter out certain columns when another corresponding column is null

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Name    A       B        C         AA   BB  cc
--------------------------------------------------------
Name1   Data1   n       Data3       3   n   15
Name2   n       Data2   Data4       n   2   8
```

I want to select A, B, or C from a row only if AA, BB, or CC is not null.

So the end would appear:

```
select Name, A,B,c from table where ??? AA<10 and BB<10 and CC<10
^I know this is dumb, just to help you understand my goal.

Name   A      B      C
-------------------------
Name1 Data1
Name2        Data2 Data4
```

Another example:

```
select Name, A,B,c from table where ??? AA<5 and BB<5 and CC<5
^I know this is dumb, just to help you understand my goal.

Name   A      B      C
-------------------------
Name1 Data1
Name2        Data2
```

One more example, for kicks:

```
select Name, A,B,c from table where ??? AA<3 and BB<3 and CC<3
^I know this is dumb, just to help you understand my goal.

Name   A      B      C
-------------------------
Name2        Data2
```

Thanks for reading!

**Here's the solution I came up with based on your help, in case anyone needs it:**

```
SELECT `Name`,
CASE
    WHEN SIGN(`AA`)>0
    THEN `A`
END A,
CASE
    WHEN SIGN(`BB`)>0
    THEN `B`
END B,
CASE
    WHEN SIGN(`CC`)>0
    THEN `C`
END C,
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: `where` filters entire rows.  If you want to only omit certain columns, but keep the rest, things get tricky.  You can get close by defining columns based on the `IF(condition,true,false)` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you mean like using [IS NOT NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null):

```
select Name, A,B,c from table where 
    AA IS NOT NULL AND BB IS NOT NULL 
    AND CC IS NOT NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT Name, 
CASE WHEN AA IS NOT NULL 
    THEN A ELSE NULL AS acol,
CASE WHEN BB IS NOT NULL
    THEN B ELSE NULL AS bcol,
CASE WHEN CC IS NOT NULL
    THEN C ELSE NULL AS ccol
FROM table WHERE your_other_conditions
```

Comment: If you read through his examples, he wants a where clause for `???` that is somehow column-granular.  In example 1, the row with Name1 appears in the desired result set but only col A is copied because BB failed NOT NULL and CC was bigger than 10.  This seems like a hard problem or a use case for defining the SELECT columns with IF()

Comment: Fascinating.  Wasn't aware of `CASE`

Comment: Here's the solution I came up with based on your help, in case anyone needs it:

    SELECT `Name`,
    CASE
        WHEN SIGN(`AA`)>0
        THEN `A`
    END A,
    CASE
        WHEN SIGN(`BB`)>0
        THEN `B`
    END B,
    CASE
        WHEN SIGN(`CC`)>0
        THEN `C`
    END C,
    FROM TABLE;